# Why doesn't Jmeter log me out when looping?

Tags: http, jmeter, performance-testing

I run Jmeter on a internal server(not on the internet).

I first log into the webpage, do some actions on the site, then log out.

If i run one or several threads(users), with only 1 "loop count", the user gets logged out from the webpage.

The problem occurs when i do more then 1 "loop count", then the users stays logged in on the webpage after the script is finished. We have only got some licenses for the webpage to use, so that's a problem for us.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter will do log you out. As the `loop count` is more than 1, all the requests under the `Thread Group` will get re-executed again for the same user. So - the user logs in, does some action and logs out, for loo count 2 - again the same user logs in, does some action and logs out..keeps going on as per the loop count.

**Number of Threads:**

This is the number of virtual users you would want to simulate using JMeter.

**Loop Count:** 
   This is number of iterations JMeter has to execute the entire test for each user.

ie, You have 10 users and 10 loop count, JMeter would have executed the test (10*10) 100 times.

Comment: Well, this is how i want it to work, the problem is that when the whole execution is finished, it doesn't log out the users..